# virtual box error

Tags: 13.04, windows-7, virtualbox

i'm trying to install Windows 7 on the Virtualbox when it trys to start up it will stop and say status: 0xc0000225 and wont open Windows. I have tried several different .iso files of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The following settings for your virtual machine may resolve the issue:

> - Enable IO APIC
> - Set chipset to ICH9

<sup>Source: [Virtual Box Forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=37628)</sup>